# Why does it show the same php result

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    require("conection/connect.php");
    $tag="";
    if (isset($_GET['tag']))
    $tag=$_GET['tag'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>::.Secundaria 10.::</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/everyone_format.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<div id="admin">
        <div id="lmain">
                <a href="#" title="logo" ><img src="picture/osiris.png" /></a>
                <div id="leftmanu">
                    <div >
                        <a href="?tag=home" title="HOME (Shift+Ctrl+H)">HOME</a><br />
                    </div>
                   <?php /*?> 
                    <?php 
                        $sql_menu=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  article_tbl WHERE loca_id=1");
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_menu)){
                        ?>
                         <div><a href="?tag=view&v_id=<?php echo $row['a_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></a></div>
                        <?php   
                            }
                        ?>  <?php */?>
                <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=student_entry" title="Shift+1">&nbsp;Estudiantes</a><br />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=teachers_entry" class="customer" title="Shift+2">&nbsp;Maestros</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=faculties_entry" class="customer" title="Shift+3">&nbsp;Salon</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=subject_entry" class="customer" title="Shift+4">&nbsp;Asignatura</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=score_entry" class="customer" title="Shift+5">&nbsp;Promedios</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=view_subjects" class="customer" title="Shift+6">&nbsp;Usuarios</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=tareas" class="customer" title="Shift+7">&nbsp;Tareas</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=artical_entry" class="customer" title="Shift+8">&nbsp;Entrada Articulo</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="#" class="customer" title="Shift+9">&nbsp;Acerca de Nosotros</a><br />
                    </div>
                     <div>
                        <a href="#" class="customer" title="Shift+Ctrl+C">&nbsp;Contacto </a><br />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=test_score" class="customer" title="Shift+Ctrl+T">&nbsp;Test Score</a><br />
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end of leftmanu -->
        </div><!--end of lmaim -->
        <div>
        </div>
    <div id="rmain">
        <div id="pic_manu">
            <a href="#" title="Studnt"><img src="picture/student.png" hspace="10px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Teacher"><img src="picture/teacher.png" hspace="20px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Faculties"><img src="picture/faculties.png" hspace="15px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Materia"><img src="picture/subject.png" hspace="10px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Score"><img src="picture/score.png" hspace="20px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="User"><img src="picture/user.png" hspace="10px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Location"><img src="picture/location.png" hspace="10px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Article"><img src="picture/article.png" hspace="10px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="About us"><img src="picture/about us.png" hspace="15px" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Contact"><img src="picture/contact.png" hspace="10px" /></a>
         </div><!--end of pic_manu -->
         <div id="menu2">
                <div style="width:10px; height:45px; padding:0px; margin:-20px; float:absolute;"></div>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a>Alumnos</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li id="li_submenu">
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=student_entry" class="sales">Alumnos</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_students" class="stocks">Ver Alumnos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a>Maestros</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_submenu">
                        <a href="everyone.php?tag=teachers_entry" class="order">Captura de Maestros</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_teachers" class="stocks">Ver Maestros</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a>Salones</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=faculties_entry" class=" order">Salones</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_faculties" class="customer">Ver Salones</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=entry_group" class=" order">Crear Grupo</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_grupogeneral" class="customer">Ver Grupos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a>Materias</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=subject_entry" class="order" title="Shift+4">Captura de Materias</a></li>
                     <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_subjects" class="customer">Ver Materias</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="">Promedios</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=score_entry" class="customer">Ingresar Promedio</a></li>
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="">Ver Promedio</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="" >Promedio 1ero</a>
                                    <ul>
                                                <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_scores" class="order">A</a></li>
                                                <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_scores" class="order">B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="" >Promedio 2do</a>
                                        <ul>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">A</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">B</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="" >Promedio 3ero</a>
                                    <ul>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">A</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="" >Promedio 4to</a>
                                    <ul>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">A</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="" >Promedio 5to</a>
                                    <ul>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">A</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="" >Promedio 6to</a>
                                    <ul>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">A</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="view_scores.php" tag="everyone.php" class="customer">B</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                           
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="">Usuarios</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=susers_entry" class="customer">Usuario Nuevo</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_users" class="sales">Ver Usuario</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=entry_group" class="order">Grupo Nuevo</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_grupogeneral" class="supplier">Ver Grupo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="">Tareas</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=tareas" class="customer">Captura</a></li>
                            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="">Ver Tareas</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>Espa&ntilde;ol</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toA" class="sales">1toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toB" class="sales">1toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toA" class="sales">2toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toB" class="sales">2toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3toA" class="sales">3toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3tob" class="sales">3toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toA" class="sales">4toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=Tareas4toB_Esp" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toA" class="sales">5toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toB" class="sales">5toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toA" class="sales">6toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toB" class="sales">6toB</a></li>
                                        </ul>                                       
                                    </li>
                                    </li>                                               
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>Matematicas</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toA" class="sales">1toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toB" class="sales">1toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toA" class="sales">2toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toB" class="sales">2toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3toA" class="sales">3toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3tob" class="sales">3toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toA" class="sales">4toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB_Mate" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toA" class="sales">5toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toB" class="sales">5toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toA" class="sales">6toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toB" class="sales">6toB</a></li>
                                        </ul>                                       
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>Fisica</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toA" class="sales">1toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toB" class="sales">1toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toA" class="sales">2toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toB" class="sales">2toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3toA" class="sales">3toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3tob" class="sales">3toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toA" class="sales">4toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toA" class="sales">5toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toB" class="sales">5toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toA" class="sales">6toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toB" class="sales">6toB</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>E. Fisica</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toA" class="sales">1toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toB" class="sales">1toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toA" class="sales">2toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toB" class="sales">2toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3toA" class="sales">3toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3tob" class="sales">3toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toA" class="sales">4toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toA" class="sales">5toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toB" class="sales">5toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toA" class="sales">6toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toB" class="sales">6toB</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>Artisticas</a>
                                        <ul>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toA" class="sales">1toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toB" class="sales">1toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toA" class="sales">2toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toB" class="sales">2toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3toA" class="sales">3toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3tob" class="sales">3toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toA" class="sales">4toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toA" class="sales">5toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toB" class="sales">5toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toA" class="sales">6toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toB" class="sales">6toB</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>Historia</a>
                                        <ul>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toA" class="sales">1toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toB" class="sales">1toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toA" class="sales">2toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toB" class="sales">2toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3toA" class="sales">3toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3tob" class="sales">3toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toA" class="sales">4toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toA" class="sales">5toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toB" class="sales">5toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toA" class="sales">6toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toB" class="sales">6toB</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>Taller</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="has-submenu"><a>Maestro1</a></li>
                                            <li class="has-submenu"><a>Maestro2</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="has-submenu"><a>Biologia</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <ul>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toA" class="sales">1toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas1toB" class="sales">1toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toA" class="sales">2toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas2toB" class="sales">2toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3toA" class="sales">3toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas3tob" class="sales">3toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toA" class="sales">4toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toA" class="sales">5toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas5toB" class="sales">5toB</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toA" class="sales">6toA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas6toB" class="sales">6toB</a></li>
                                        </ul>   
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a>Material</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=artical_entry" class="sales">Entrada Articulos</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="everyone.php?tag=view_artical" class="stocks">Ver Articulos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a>Examenes</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="calendario.php" tag="calendario.php" class="sales">Calendario</a></li>
                            <!-- end of leftmanu<ul>
                                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="calendario.php">Calendario</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="examen2.php?tag=location_entry">Matematicas</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                 <li id="menu"><a href="examen2.php" >1</a></li>
                                                 <li id="menu"><a href="examen2.php" >2</a></li>
                                                 <li id="menu"><a href="examen2.php" >3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has-submenu">Fisica</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has-submenu">E. Fisica</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has-submenu">Artisticas</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has-submenu">Historia</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has-submenu">Taller</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="has-submenu">Biologia</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" >1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" >2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="examen2.php" >3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul> -->
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a>Primero</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2?tag=quiz" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
                                <li id="menu li"><a href="examen2.php" tag=location_entry class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a>Segundo</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="quiz.php" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a>Tercero</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a>Cuarto</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a>Quinto</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-submenu"><a>Sexto</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Espa&ntilde;ol</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Matematicas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">E. Fisica</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Artisticas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Historia</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Taller</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="stocks">Biologia</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-submenu"><a href="">Contact</a>
                    <ul>
                         <li id="li_submenu"><a href="#" class="customer">Contact Entry</a></li>
                        <li id="li_submenu"><a href="#" class="order">Groups Contact</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
      </div><!--end of menu2--> 
            <div id="contents">
                <div id="informations">
                    <div id="in_informations">
                <?php
                        if($tag=="home" or $tag=="")
                            include("home.php");
                        elseif($tag=="student_entry")
                            include("Students_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="teachers_entry")
                            include("Teachers_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="score_entry")
                            include("Score_Entry.php"); 
                        elseif($tag=="subject_entry")
                            include("Subject_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="faculties_entry")
                            include("Faculties_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="susers_entry")
                            include("Users_Entry.php"); 
                        elseif($tag=="view_students")
                            include("View_Students.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_teachers")
                            include("View_Teachers.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_subjects")
                            include("View_Subjects.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_scores")
                            include("View_Scores.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_users")
                            include("View_Users.php");
                        /*elseif($tag=="view_faculties")
                            include("View_Faculties.php");*/
                        elseif($tag=="tareas")
                            include("tareas.php");
                        elseif($tag=="location_entry")
                            include("Location_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="artical_entry")
                            include("Artical_Entry.php");
                        elseif($tag=="View_Tareas")
                            include("View_Tareas.php");
                        elseif($tag=="test_score")
                            include("test_Scores .php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_location")
                            include("View_location.php");
                        elseif($tag=="entry_group")
                            include("entry_group.php");
                        elseif($tag=="view_grupogeneral")
                            include("view_grupogeneral.php");
                        elseif($tag="Tareas4toB_Esp")
                            include("Tareas4toB_Esp.php");
                        elseif($tag="View_Tareas4toB_Mate")
                            include("View_Tareas4toB_Mate.php");
                        elseif($tag="view_artical")
                            include("View_Articaly.php");
                            /*$tag= $_REQUEST['tag'];
                            if(empty($tag)){
                                include ("Students_Entry.php");
                            }
                            else{
                                include $tag;
                            }*/
                        ?>
                    </div><!--end of in_informations -->
                </div><!--end of informations -->
            </div><!--end of contens -->   
     </div><!--end of rmain -->
    </div><!--end of admin -->
</body>
</html>
```

It is here the first part where it is showing me the result

```
 ---href="everyone.php?tag=Tareas4toB_Esp"---
```

and it is ok but when I try to select the second example

```
---href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB_Mate"---
```

It is the example and that one is the another when I tried to access in the `View_Tareas4toB_Mate` just it is showing me the `Tareas4toB_esp` and I put the variables and it doesnt change...

Comment: <li><a href="everyone.php?tag=Tareas4toB_Esp" class="sales">4toB</a></li>
 are you talking about this line? in this line view_ is missing

Comment: Yes... this line  php page appears also when I have selected href="everyone.php?tag=View_Tareas4toB_Mate and if  a put other one  appears again...

Comment: you **MUST NOT** use `mysql_xxx` functions which are deprecated since php5.5 (more than 3 years ago) and removed since PHP7 because of security issues (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/3992945). Please use `mysqli_xxx` or `PDO` instead php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

Comment: jyoti mishra I am sorry but well the files is called just like that because I was trying changing the name thinking that maybe the cache of the computer processor or browser makes this error but I saw that the error still are there...

Comment: Well that mysql option is hidden is not working on the website I understood what do you means... BUT I saw that this problem becomes in the variables that I have at the bottom of the code like this variables elseif($tag="Tareas4toB_Esp")
       include("Tareas4toB_Esp.php");
      elseif($tag="View_Tareas4toB_Mate")
       include("View_Tareas4toB_Mate.php"); I do not what else I can do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
  elseif($tag="Tareas4toB_Esp")
                        include("Tareas4toB_Esp.php");
                    elseif($tag="View_Tareas4toB_Mate")
                        include("View_Tareas4toB_Mate.php");
                    elseif($tag="view_artical")
                        include("View_Articaly.php");
```

You are using = to define $tag. this is why it will always show Tareas4toB_Esp.php because it defines $tag.

You have to use == to use for comparison like you did in your previous IF statements like this:

```
  elseif($tag=="Tareas4toB_Esp")
                        include("Tareas4toB_Esp.php");
                    elseif($tag=="View_Tareas4toB_Mate")
                        include("View_Tareas4toB_Mate.php");
                    elseif($tag=="view_artical")
                        include("View_Articaly.php");
```

Comment: thank you buddy... I saw it was very little the error, I was very tired, when I did it, but thanks a lot that you take your time to help me to find it... :)